# Access data from child component without rendering parent component React-js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I am passing data from parent component to child component through `<Route />`. This works fine and I can see the output of data in `console.log()` from child component. However, this works perfectly only when I am opening the parent component first and then navigate to the child component.

I have put data to console from the render method and I see in the initial run at parent component, data is pushed twice to the console the initial one being null and the second one with actual data.

When I call the data directly from child component, I only see one output in the console which is null. I want to access data directly from child component without navigating through parent component.

I have tried changing the component lifecycles but nothing worked.

Below is code for my parent component.

```
class Main extends React.Component{
  constructor(props){
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      data: []
    }
  }

  componentWillMount(){
    this.importJSON()
  }

  importJSON(){
    return fetch ("https://bitbucket.org/...")
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(responseJson => {
      this.setState({
        data: responseJson.fulldata
       })       
     })
   }

   render(){
     console.log(this.state.data) //This renders twice in parent is rendered.
     return(
       <main>
        <Switch>
          <Route exact path='/' component={Home}/>
          <Route path='/Chord' render={()=><Chord value={this.state.data}/>}/>        
        </Switch>
      </main>
    )
  }
}
export default Main
```

How can I have data called in child component directly from parent component without navigating from parent component?

**EDIT:**
Function from child component(Chord) where the prop is called

```
importData(){
const newData = this.props.value;
}
```

`const newData` is then passed on to the visualization. If I load Chord component directly in console I see a null array. If chord is navigated from Parent component (Main) then it works fine.

Comment: By child you are referring to the Chord component?

Comment: Yea, that's right.

Comment: what do you mean by navigate from parent? do you mean `Home` the whole time?  in the code you posted you can never navigate away from `Main`

Comment: I edited the code with function where the data is being called. When put the same to console I get null if chord is loaded directly. If its navigated through Home then it works fine.

Comment: so if you `console.log` right after that `newData` assignment, you get nothing?

Comment: Ya. I get nothing when I directly render chord. But I get data in console if I’m navigating through Home.